# Compare two times in HH:MM:SS format - ksh

Tags: shell-script, ksh, date

Is it possible to compare two time (24-hour format)? What I need is to just check if the first time is earlier than the second time.

Example:

```
$ ./script.ksh 09:30:15 13:00:34
okay
$ ./script.ksh 05:25:00 02:30:50
invalid arguments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When those two values are in a variable like this:

```
a="09:30:15"
b="13:00:34"
```

Then you can use this to compare those values (with `ksh93`):

```
[ "${a//':'}" -lt "${b//':'}" ] && echo "okay" || echo "invalid arguments"
```

This uses `ksh`s parameter expansion `${parameter//pattern/string}`. From the manpage:

> Expands  parameter  and  replaces  the longest match of pattern with the given string.
>   [...]
>   Each match for pattern is replaced by the given string.

So `09:30:15` expands to `093015` and `13:00:34` to `130434`. Those are integers that can be compared by the `test` utility. From the man page:

> ```
>    INTEGER1 -lt INTEGER2
>           INTEGER1 is less than INTEGER2
> ```

---

**Edit**: with `ksh88` which hasn't the feature `${parameter//pattern/string}`, you have to remove the `:` with `sed` first and then compare the values:

```
a="$(printf '%s' "$a" | sed -e 's/://g')"
b="$(printf '%s' "$b" | sed -e 's/://g')"
[ "$a" -lt "$b" ]  && echo "okay" || echo "invalid arguments"
```

Comment: i am getting this error `0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.`

Comment: do you mean `ksh` or `ksh93`?

Comment: @erin00 See my edited answer. This should work now with your ksh version.

Comment: @erin00 The error message you posted indicates that the `${a//x/y/}` notation is not supported which was the case with `ksh88`. So I assumed `ksh88`. But I'm not a ksh expert and I only have a `ksh93` (`sh (AT&T Research) 93u 2011-02-08`) here to test. But however, with the edit in my answer it should also work with your ksh version, give it a try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
ksh -c '
    IFS=: x=2
    set ${0+09:30:15} ${0+13:00:34}
    for t do eval "
        [ ${t#0} -lt \"\${$((x+=1))#0}\" ]" && break
    done &&
    echo "$1:$2:$3 is earlier than $4:$5:$6"
'
```

---

```
09:30:15 is earlier than 13:00:34
```